# Bootstrap container containing a row

Tags: html, css

I'm building a project for my coding bootcamp and I built a bootstrap container containing a bootstrap row (full row; with no col). How do I get the two left and right borders to touch (no space in between)? I was able to close the gap between the two left, but somehow, there's still a space between the two right.
How can I fix that?
Thanks

```
            .container{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 1140px;
   border: 4px solid green;
   }


  .middle-about-me {
   /*this is the row*/
   background-color: #dbe4f0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 650px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   border: 3px blue solid;
  }
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the bootstrap container has a default margin or padding i guess. Maybe try to put margin and padding to 0 with

```
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
```

To rewrite an bootstrap property you need to add !important at the end